# Как создать 2 экземпляра одной формы?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать 2 экземпляра одной формы? Если писать

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form11);
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form12);
```

то компилятор ругается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так создавайте правильно.

```
var f1:TForm1;
    f2:TForm2;
begin
    f1 := TForm1.Create(Application);
    f2 := TForm1.Create(Application);
    f1.show();
    f2.show();
end;
```

Только потом нужно не забыть вызвать деструкторы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.